# Deflection of starlight by the sun

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

I found the deflection by using SR+QM+Newtonian gravitation. I would like to see how I can calculate by GR. Can anyone show me how to calculate by using GR &Schwarcshild metric

What I did:

$\Delta{P_\perp} = \int F_\perp dt = \int \frac{GMm}{r^2}cos\phi dt$

r is the distance from center of mass(sun). R is impact parameter. $\phi$ is the angle between r and R.

$\frac{R}{r}=cos\phi$

$dt = \frac{dx}{c}$

$x = Rtan\phi$
$dx= \frac{R}{cos^2\phi}d\phi$

$\Delta P_\perp =\int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi/2} \frac{GMm}{R^2}cos^2\phi.cos\phi \frac{Rd\phi}{c .cos^2\phi}  = \frac{2GMm}{cR} = \frac{2GM}{cR} \frac{hf}{c^2}$

Deflection $=\frac{ \Delta P_\perp}{\Delta P} = \frac{2GM}{c^2R}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Bending_of_light_by_gravity for the derivation in GR.